# Showing updated data in final activity

Tags: android

I have 3 activities: A, B, C.
In activity A, I get Name and Surname from the user and pass it to activity B through Intent.
In activity B, I get Number1 and Number 2 and pass Name, Surname, Number1 and Number2 to activity C where I show them in TextViews.
I want to change data in activity B, but if I change and pass the updated numbers to activity C, Name and Surname from activity A disappear in activity C.
How can I retain the non changed data in the final activity?

Activity A

```
public void button1(View v)
{
    EditText personName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textName);
    EditText surname= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.surname);

    name = personName.getText().toString();
    secondname = surname.getText().toString();

    Intent go = new Intent(this, activityB.class);
    go.putExtra("name", name);
    go.putExtra("secondname", secondname);
    startActivity(go);

}
```

Activity B

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_numbers);

Intent info = getIntent();
String name = info.getStringExtra(name, "");
String surname = info.getStringExtra(secondname, "");


}


public void button2(View v)
{
EditText number1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.number1);
EditText number2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.number2);

num1 = number1.getText().toString();
num2 = number2.getText().toString();

Intent go = new Intent(this, activityB.class);
go.putExtra("number1", num1);
go.putExtra("number2", num2);
go.putExtra("name", name);
go.putExtra("secondname", secondname);
startActivity(go);

}
```

Activity C

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_final);

Intent info = getIntent();
String name = info.getStringExtra(name, "");
String surname = info.getStringExtra(secondname, "");
int number1 = info.getIntExtra(number1, 0);
int number2 = info.getIntExtra(number12, 0);

 ...Show them in TextView
}
```

I have then a button in activity C that send me to A or B to change data. If I change data only in B, I loose the data of A in activity C.

Any help is welcome.

Thanks, Marco

Comment: You need to post relevant code snippets so we can see what you are doing.

Comment: pass through bundle.

Comment: I think you need to create name and surname parameteres in Activity B outside the onCreate method as global variables and then assign them values in onCreate.

Answer (score 1):

It'd really help having your code posted!  But basically, the easiest implementation is the make data persistent.  The objects you pass around are 2 strings and 2 numbers - that is perfect for making persistent through shared preferences!

Here's a link that explains how to implement such a solution to make your data persistent: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Basically, you'll need to create key-value sets, which means a string identifying a key and then a string/double/int that contains the data you want to persist.

Feel free to provide more info and code so we can help you better!

Comment: needs to check for local data storage.